# Assistance with JSON functions in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-2016, json-value

I have a SQL Server table with the following format:

```
ID               int
JobParameters    nvarchar(max)
```

where JobParameters column contains for example:

```
{
    "Parameters": [
        {
            "SID": 35,
            "RPYID": 10
        }, {
            "SID": 36,
            "RPYID": 10
        }, {
            "SID": 39,
            "RPYID": 10
        }, {
            "SID": 46,
            "RPYID": 10
        }, {
            "SID": 58,
            "RPYID": 10
        }, {
            "SID": 65,
            "RPYID": 10
        }, {
            "SID": 71,
            "RPYID": 10
        }, {
            "SID": 72,
            "RPYID": 10
        }, {
            "SID": 73,
            "RPYID": 10
        }, {
            "SID": 74,
            "RPYID": 10
        }, {
            "SID": 78,
            "RPYID": 10
        }, {
            "SID": 80,
            "RPYID": 10
        }, {
            "SID": 81,
            "RPYID": 10
        }, {
            "SID": 82,
            "RPYID": 10
        }, {
            "SID": 88,
            "RPYID": 10
        }, {
            "SID": 90,
            "RPYID": 10
        }, {
            "SID": 96,
            "RPYID": 10
        }, {
            "SID": 407,
            "RPYID": 10
        }, {
            "SID": 408,
            "RPYID": 10
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to insert the SID and RPYID from the JobParameters (JSON) into another table.

So basically need to efficiently convert JSON value stored in one table to two columns in another table.

Comment: Do you mean the SQL-2016 standard, or that MS product with an easily confused name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`OPENJSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) like so:

```
SELECT ID, j.SID, j.RPYID
FROM t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(JobParameters, '$.Parameters')
WITH (   
    SID int '$.SID',  
    RPYID int '$.RPYID'
) AS j
```

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a5fa2bb967261c0d219d1c9a3c664d9c)